# Samsung SmartTV overlay video

Tags: javascript, html, samsung-smart-tv, television

I need a video to playing under content. I clear background(html,body, and other divs) and it is work but I need to put shadows on the video by `img.png`. When I add shadows via `img.png` for tag body my player disappears but I hear sound.

I think the problem is due to picture format. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Samsung Video Player (INFOLINK-PLAYER) is always appear in the last layer of application, even behind the `<body>` or `<html>`. So when you add img.png it seems your img.png is covering the player, that's why you're hearing only sound.

My suggestion is to set the img.png with transparent color in the area where you want to show the video.